# remove the last n lines from all files of a certain type in the current directory, recursive

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script.

```
for i in **/*.h; do head $i -n -2 > $i.tmp && mv $i.tmp $i -f; done
```

The purpose is to run over every .h file inside the current directory and remove the last two lines from that file.

However this does only work as intended on files that are located directly in subfolders of the current directory, but it doesn't process files inside subfolder of subfolders and so on, so ./foo/foobar.h gets processed, but ./foo/bar/foobar.h or for/bar/foobar/.foobar.h don't.

Therefor I have tried it this way:

```
for i in 'find -name *.h'; do head $i -n -2 > $i.tmp && mv $i.tmp $i -f; done
```

This fails, because > $i.tmp is ambiguous

How should my script look so that it processes all the header files in a directory, no matter, how deeply they are nested in subfolders?

EDIT:
If the original file hasn't had a newline directly before eof, the working first script from above (and also the sed alternative from the answers) will add one, so if a newline before eof isn't desired, it has to be removed afterwards:

```
for i in **/*.h; do head $i -n -2 > $i.tmp && mv $i.tmp $i -f && truncate --size=-2 $i; done
```

size should be -2 for CRLF (Windows style) newline and -1 for both, CR (old MacOS style) and LF (unix style), line endings

Of course this approach will also remove a newline before eof, that has already been there before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet should work if you have [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) and

```
shopt -s globstar
```

enabled.

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: btw.: Do you have any idea, why globstar isn't enabled by default in bash4?

Comment: Depends of your distro settings and your own settings. It's enabled by default on archlinux.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name '*.h' -exec sed -i 'N;$!P;$!D;$d' '{}' ';'
```

This will delete the last two lines from all .h files, and eliminates the need for redirection and temp files, since it edits the files in place. It will also work with filenames and paths that contain spaces.

Comment: It's not quite true, `sed` create temp files for you in the background.

Comment: @sputnick: You're right. I meant explicit temp files, which make your one-liner longer and more prone to errors with exotic file names.

Comment: phew - I don't really get the syntax of this: for example your code doesn't specify any numbers, so how does sed know how many lines to delete?

Comment: It's keeping two lines in the buffer at all times (the N adds another line, embedding a newline). Then, if it is not the last line ($!), it prints and deletes the first line (up to the newline) in the buffer and starts over (the D has that side effect). On the last line, though, the print/delete is skipped and the two lines in the buffer are deleted by the $d which is only reached on the last line.